# Please tell me JavaScript RegEx for : A.12345678.123 that is start with 'A.' followed by 8 digits [0-9] followed by '.' and again by 3 digits[0-9]

Tags: javascript, regex

Please tell me JavaScript RegEx for : A.12345678.123 that is start with 'A.' followed by 8 digits and followed by '.' and again by 3 digits.

Comment: That's about the most trivial regex imaginable. What problem do you have in constructing it yourself? And please don't say that you don't know regexen, because then you should *learn* them.

Comment: Please start at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), then ask here, if you get stucked.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the place to come and let other people write code for you. Show some effort on your own. If you run into troubles we will certainly help you.

Comment: Try to learn RegEx first and come here only after you have tried something, with some code ;)

Comment: Hi, 

try this :-

"^A\..\{9\}\..\{\3\}"

Comment: And what you all intelligent people will say to a person who is not into Java yet needs to correct something urgently????

Comment: By the way .. thank you deceze, Teemu, TheGippoand tsippert. Thanks a lot and pls get well soon.

Comment: And was it that much faster and *beneficial* to post a question here than to try to grok the basics of regexen yourself? See http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This for matching full string:

```
/^A\.\d{8}.\d{3}$/
```

to match part of string remove ^ or $.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:-

```
/^A\.[0-9]{8}\.[0-9]{3}$/
```